# Help identifying a Scifi series of Novels from the 80's with Robot Overlords

Tags: story-identification, novel

These were a series of novels that I read as a kid in the 80s or early 90s. Humanity was ruled by AI/robot overlords and the plot revolved around a group of humans trying to get two keys to a certain control room at the same time so that they could shut down the robots.

One other character was a being of unknown origin who could steal the form and maybe the memories of its victims. They would fuse their body with their victim and later emerge with their new form. They did not know their true purpose, at least in the earlier books.

I think that I read 2 or 3 books but I lost track and never found out how it ended.

Comment: I recommend visiting https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question to find more questions to answer to improve your question.

Comment: It sounds like a half remembered "Rings of the Masters"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going agree that this is most likely Chalker's [*Rings of the Master*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?1792) books, published between 1986 and 1988.

Humanity has been subjugated by an AI known as the "Master System" that has eliminated much human technology and is trying to force the remaining population into a low-tech existence.  The story arises as a group of people find evidence of a set of 5 rings (which are computer keys) that can be used to take control of and/or shut down the Master System.

(At one point there is some discussion that the computer has certain rules that it *can't* break, like making sure the rings exist and are at least nominally accessible.  But it's free to define "accessible" in a way that requires a starship to collect them, regardless of how practical that would be for people it is trying to reduce to hunter-gatherers.)

The being that can absorb other people's forms and memories isn't an alien; it was actually created on the "prison" asteroid Melchior by Clayben and his allies as a weapon to use against the Master System.  It initially appears as Reba Koll in the second book [*Pirates of the Thunder*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?3670) where it takes/absorbs the piratical captain Sabatini and takes his form.  It takes the name Vulture and joins with the heroes.  It has a larger and more open role in the following books.

There are 4 books in the series, so that fits with it being incomplete after 2 or 3 books.

[image: Cover of Lord of the Middle Dark]
[image: Cover of Pirates of the Thunder]
[image: Cover of Warriors of the Storm]
[image: Cover of Masks of the Martyr]

Comment: I think that this must be the series that I was looking for. I had searched for it a couple of times in the past but never found it. Thanks so much.